# Traveling salesman in Gurobi/Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, gurobi

I am trying to learn Gurobi and having a little bit of trouble understanding how the functions work.

I have a matrix with the distance to different places, it looks as follows:

```
places = {}
places[“A”,”A”] = 0
places[“A”,”B”] = 10
places[“A”,”C”] = 20

places[“B”,”A”] = 10
places[“B”,”B”] = 0
places[“B”,”C”] = 15

places[“C”,”A”] = 20
places[“C”,”B”] = 15
places[“C”,”C”] = 0
```

I now what to find the shortest path between all the different locations (visit all locations one time).

I have looked at the addVar and addConstr function but I am not really sure how to make use of these functions on this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Gurobi contains a complete TSP example in Python, see `tsp.py`in the `examples/python`folder.